# Django NoReverseMatch Error for 'questions' View After Google OAuth Sign-In

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I'm working on a Django project with Google OAuth implemented. The homepage (index.html) loads correctly, and the Google OAuth sign-in functions as expected. However, I'm encountering a NoReverseMatch error when trying to redirect to the questions view after sign-in.

Error Message:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'questions' not found. 'questions' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
...
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'questions' not found. 'questions' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://8000-lmcrean-classroommatrix-zp6cz7sdhxw.ws-eu106.gitpod.io/
Django Version: 3.2.23
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'questions' not found. 'questions' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: /workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py, line 698, in _reverse_with_prefix
Python Executable:  /home/gitpod/.pyenv/versions/3.9.17/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.9.17
[...]

Error during template rendering

In template /workspace/Classroom-Matrix/templates/base.html, error at line 45

Reverse for 'questions' not found. 'questions' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
[...]
45                          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'questions' %}">Top Questions</a>
```

## debugging steps

below I have reviewed the problem areas and tried solving adjustments.

### templates/base.html

same error message appears when changing `'questions'` to `'index'` in line 45. to Top Questions - leads to `" 'index' is not a valid view function or pattern name."`

does not seem likely to be root of problem.

### blog/urls.py

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('like/<slug:slug>', views.PostLike.as_view(), name='post_like'),
]
```

this is a very likely problem area that I am currently investigating creating a `'questions/'` path

Answer (score 0):

The issue of the NoReverseMatch error for the 'questions' view in Django is resolved by properly configuring the URL patterns in blog/urls.py.

The error occurred because Django could not find a URL pattern named 'questions'. This was resolved by adding a corresponding path to the urlpatterns list in blog/urls.py. The added path directs requests to the appropriate view function, which in this case is `PostList.as_view()`.

```
# Corrected urlpatterns in blog/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('like/<slug:slug>', views.PostLike.as_view(), name='post_like'),
    path('questions/', views.PostList.as_view(), name='questions'),
]
```

The code now displays the correct view after OAuth signin.